# kettle sample rows for each type

Tags: kettle

I have a set of rows let's say "rowId","type","value". I need on output set of 10 sample rows for each "type". How can I do it? "type" has aprox. 100 different, and changing values, so switch is not good option.

Comment: Do you need special values for the "type" column or do they only need to be unique?

Comment: only 10 sample rows for every "type" colum value, no matter what the value is

Comment: Sounds like you need an enhancement in PDI - The existing reservoir sampling step modified to support groups. That would be quite neat - be worth suggesting it on jira.pentaho.com !  Obviously it can be done as per your solution below, or in fact simply by adding a rownum which resets on each type, and then filtering where rownum < 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've figured a walkaround from this situation. I splited transformation in parts. First part collects all data to a temp table, finds unique types, and copies them to the result.

The second one runs for every input row (where we have types), and collects data of a given type from temp table. Then you need no grouping to do stratified sample.

Comment: Did you look at the Reservoir Sampling step?